# Accidentally ran "rm -rf /" on macOS

Tags: rm, macos

A friend mentioned to me that he couldn't believe that the command to delete everything on a unix system was only eight characters long. I told him that you actually needed to use "--no-preserve-root". I tried to demonstrate this by running "rm -rf /" in Alacritty, not realizing that I had used `su` and forgot to exit. Apparently, on macOS 11.2.3, you don't need to use `--no-preserve-root`. It took me two whole seconds to realize what had happened. I was wondering if there was a tool that can scan macOS and determine damage to the system. I am using M1.

Comment: SIP won't generally allow actual system damage on macOS, but user and application files can be deleted; what sort of damage are you concerned about?

Comment: I would recommend reinstall

Comment: Why don't you just boot your Mac and see what's up?

Comment: Restore backups ;)